# Python system call (os.system) doesn't work as expected with the same string in two cases

Tags: python, path, system-calls, os.system

I'm doing the exact same thing in these two cases, but case 1 doesn't work. Anyone knows why Python behaves this way?

```
# Case 1
setup_folder = "/home/svimal/Data/ABoVE/100_catchments/VIC_setup/05MG001/"
os.system('../VIC_4.1.2.k.Purdue/vicNl -g  ' + setup_folder + "/Global_Param")
# Case 2
os.system("../VIC_4.1.2.k.Purdue/vicNl -g /home/svimal/Data/ABoVE/100_catchments/VIC_setup/05MG001/GlobalParam")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will create an argument `/home/svimal/Data/ABoVE/100_catchments/VIC_setup/05MG001//Global_Param` - note the `//` before "Global_Param".

You could use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to avoid having to deal with these slashes yourself:

```
arg = os.path.join('/home/svimal/Data/ABoVE/100_catchments/VIC_setup/05MG001/', 'Global_Param')
os.system('../VIC_4.1.2.k.Purdue/vicNl -g  ' + arg)
```